# Trying to port existing powershell-depending class library from .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core

I have .NET Framework class library with some code using older Powershell:

```
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Management.Automation;

//some code executing powershell commands in runspaces and processing results, similar to this:
    var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
                powerShell.Commands.AddScript(psscript);
                results = powerShell.Invoke();
                //process results, etc...
            }
```

I'm trying to port it to .NET Core, using package `Microsoft.Powershell.SDK` with Powershell Core. It works fine for the most part, but for obvious reasons it can't run legacy powershell commands (`add-pssnapin`, etc).

This class library is intended to be used on a wide range of machines, some of them requiring those old powershell commands to work and others requiring to use Powershell Core. How do I achieve this?

The only solution I can think of is making two separate projects, one of them for .NET Framework and another for .NET Core, but having two projects with same code(except for 4-5 lines with those old commands) seems like a bad idea. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this a PowerShell Module (i.e., code that implements Cmdlets or PSCmdlets) or is it something else?  Do you really use Snapins (they haven't been around for a while I believe).

Comment: @Flydog57 No, code is just executing powershell commands in runspaces and processes results. Executing commands, howerver, requires old third party snapins in some cases.